# Biological explosives

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology, fauna, anatomy

I want an organism to be capable of producing Diethylzinc or any other similar substance which on contact with external air explodes or ignites.

The creature can be as complex as an animal or it can be just a peculiar bacteria, it doesn't matter.

I just want something capable of producing such materials for whatever reason...

How and why would an organism produce explosive/igniferous substances that react easily, possibly on contact with air?

Comment: Why: Because it was genetically engineered to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bombardier beetle produces a boiling steam spray by mixing hydroquinone and hydrogen peroxide. These are produced from separate glands in its body and react explosively. These substances are produced by the beetle as a defence mechanism.

Theoretically there are lots of possibilities for a defensive weapon based on a range of chemicals. Diethylzinc is probably less likely unless zinc is readily available in the environment in large quantities.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle